# How can we send a customised email using Jenkins if there is 100% test cases failure?

Tags: testing, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, email-notifications

I would like Jenkins to send a customised email if 100% of the test cases in the Project fail. Normal email notification doesn't have such option.

I looked for other plugins as well, but couldn't find any useful information.

Does anyone know how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

if you using declarative pipeline u should use post clausule `https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post` 
and in this block for exmaple:

```
mail (to: "abc@abc.com",
         from: "urmail@abc.com",
         subject: "bla bla",
         body: """line 1
           line 2
           line 3
           line 3""");
```

Comment: How do we make Jenkins know that all the test cases in the first run failed, so instead of re-running the scripts, send an email to people with a customized subject line?

we are using Serenity for report generation- now that i have a report with passed/failures %, can Jenkins read the values from there and based on that can it take a call whether to re-run it or just stop the execution?